# Unexpected Syntax error with AnsiString [] access when volatile is used

Tags: compiler-errors, c++builder

Recently, I needed to use `volatile AnsiString`, and hit some walls like this:

```cpp
volatile AnsiString s;
s="123456";
s[2]='X'; // <- [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(17): E2277 Lvalue required
```

**Q1 Why is this causing a compile error?**

This is on BDS 2006, I did not try RAD Studio 11 yet (I need this in legacy code).

I can workaround it like this:

```cpp
volatile AnsiString s;
s="123456";
char *c=s.c_str(); c[1]='X';
```

But I would like to know what is happening.

**Q2 Is there any better option instead of `AnsiString` which works better with `volatile`?**

Comment: WHY do you need the `AnsiString` to be `volatile`? That makes no sense, and in my 25+ years of using C++Builder I have NEVER ONCE seen anyone ever need to use `volatile` with `AnsiString` (or any other string class). What is the use-case here?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Me neither, the `AnsiString` its used as part (member) of (very old) class that is shared between threads. The problem arises from Win10 and newer OS something changed in process scheduling again making old legacy code to throw occasional exceptions (inside locked/critical section VCL/RTL code of AnsiString itself) with multi-threading but only on some  machines (circumstances are still unknown) so I tried to use `volatile`  just to test if it helps or not before I rewrite the stuff completely which will take a while ... as its ~20 years old legacy code

Comment: Volatile will not help with this problem. All it does is tell the compiler not to optimise away any use(s) of the variable. If you have poorly constructed interfacing between threads you need to dig in and find where the problem is and solve it by using correct locking approaches.

Comment: @RogerCigol its weird but it looks like (after 3 days of 24/7 testing on infected machines) that the `volatile AnsiString` (along with above workaround)  helped my issue even if volatile should really not be needed as also Remy mentioned (it was inside already locked code) but it might be just coincidence only time will tell as this thing is  not easily reproducible. **But we got side tracked as the question is about compiler error instead of multithread locking issues...**